# MySQL JOIN not working properly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I know this has been asked alot - but it's not a duplicate of anything I've been able to find.
I'm simpy trying to get the rating of each song for each user.

Here's my tables:

[image]

`ratings.uid` has a foreign_key relationship with `users.USERID`
`ratings.sid` has a foreign_key relationship with `songs.ID`

I want to be able to query something like: `WHERE users.USERID = 3`):

```
----------------------------------
USERID  |  SONGTITLE  |  RATING
----------------------------------
  3     |   Song #1   |    1
----------------------------------
  3     |   Song #2   |    3 
----------------------------------
  3     |   Song #3   |    4
----------------------------------
  3     |   Song #4   |    5
```

This is the closest I can get...and its wrong:

```
SELECT users.USERID, songs.SONGTITLE, ratings.rating
FROM users,songs
INNER JOIN ratings
ON users.USERID = ratings.uid
WHERE users.USERID = 3
```

I get an error:  `unknown column "users.USERID" in "on clause"`

Can anyone help??

Comment: I don't know that you can do a Cartesian product AND a Join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a query that uses only `Joins`, I don't believe you can mix and match Cartesian product with Joins.

```
Select u.USERID, s.SONGTITLE, r.rating
From   users u Join
       ratings r On u.USERID = r.uid Join
       songs s On r.sid = s.ID
Where  u.USERID = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the following:

```
SELECT users.USERID, songs.SONGTITLE, ratings.rating
FROM users  
INNER JOIN ratings ON users.USERID = ratings.uid
INNER JOIN songs ON songs.ID = ratings.sid 
WHERE users.USERID = 3
```

Comment: I get `Unknown column 'songs.SONGTITLE' in 'field list'

Comment: **@bagofmilk**, I don't understand why you were having a problem.  This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e389/1/0) demonstrates the above query working with your table structure and sample data.